# How to properly install Facebook Ads for IOS using React Native

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I'm getting a warning in React Native when trying to launch my app via IOS:

"Module AdChoiceManager requires main queue setup
since it overrides 'init' but doesn't implement
'requiresMainQueueSetup'. In a future release
React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of."

In my podfile, I have these

```
pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '~> 5.1.0'
```

I get the error:

```
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
npm install --production

/bin/bash: line 2: npm: command not found
```

So I tried this:

```
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '~> 5.1.0' 
  pod 'FacebookSDK'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

Everything installs but I still get the warning. It works fine on Android, I'm just not sure how to get Facebook Ads working properly, without warning on IOS.

My question is, how do I resolve this issue/warning? I've been trying for days to get this off the screen to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the dependency. It is not a major issue but it will require fixing by the dependency maintainer in the future.

It is to do with the queue/thread the dependency is running on. It only affects iOS.

There is nothing you can do at the moment to remove the warning.

You could just hide the yellow warning box but it will still log the warning in your console.

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Module AdChoiceManager requires main queue setup since']);
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#in-app-errors-and-warnings

I'm not 100% sure that is the correct text to use for blocking it, but it will be something similar to that. Usually I just the text from the start of the warning

#### To fix the issue

The only way to solve the issue is to fix it in the dependency its self. You will have to fork the repo that is causing the issue, make the change, create a pull request and wait for Facebook to merge your change. While you’re waiting you can use your own fork.

Inside the correct file, it will end in `... Manager.m` You just have to add the line

```
+ (BOOL) requiresMainQueueSetup { return YES; }
```

There maybe more than one place this has to be done dependening in how they have set it up the dependency. This will stop the warning as you will told the dependency which queue it requires.

Warning, you will now have to maintain your own version of the dependency until such times that Facebook implement your pull request.

Comment: Thanks! Although I'd rather resolve the issue than mitigate it, this is a great suggestion.

Comment: The only way to solve the issue is to fix it in the dependency. So fork the repo that is causing the issue, make the change, create a pull request and wait for Facebook to merge your change. While you’re waiting you can use your own fork. You just have to add `+(BOOL)requiresMainQueueSetup { return YES; }` in the correct place.